# JavaFX ProgressBar for TabPane

Tags: javafx-2

I am interested in showing a progressbar while i switch to a different tab on my main tabpane. The tabs on my tabpane takes sometime(5-10 sec) before actually appearing. I want the progressbar to appear while the tab switching is taking place.

Comment: Why are the tabs slow to appear? Are you loading data from somewhere which you are displaying?

Comment: Each tab is complex with multiple controls and lot of data from database queries.

Answer (score 3):

Download the data in a separate Task<T>, where T is a type that encapsulates all the data. Set the content of the tab to a progress bar; register an onSucceeded handler with the Task which sets the content of the tab to the display of the data, then start the task.

So this will look something like:

```
final Tab tab = ... ;
final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
final Task<MyDataType> loadDataTask = new Task<MyDataType>() {
  @Override
  public MyDataType call() throws Exception {
    // download data...
    MyDataType result = ... ;
    return result ;
  }
};
tab.setContent(progressBar);
loadDataTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
    MyDataType data = loadDataTask.getValue();
    Node tabContent = ... ; // build tab content from data
    tab.setContent(tabContent);
  }
});
final Thread thread = new Thread(loadDataTask);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Do not update any UI elements that are part of the scene graph in the Task's call(...) method. If you can measure the progress of the data download and want to show it in the progressBar (instead of an indeterminate progress bar), you can do

```
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(loadDataTask.progressProperty());
```

and then in the Task's call method, call

```
updateProgress(amountDone, totalAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @James_D. However i noticed that maximum time is taken for the controls to load rather than the database queries. My tabs are configured to load separate fxml with their controllers.
Is there any way i can load controllers as separate task ?

Comment: You can, but that loading the controls should be quick (unless, I suppose, you are loading from an FXML over a slow network, or something strange). If you're loading FXML files with associated controllers, are the controllers loading data which is taking a long time? If that's the case, you may want to either have the controller manage that in a task, and put progress bars as placeholders, or reorganise things considerably (load the data separately, pass the data to a controller and the controller to the FXML loader).

Comment: If you really need, though, you can make a Task<Node> and delegate the entire loading process to the task. Use the same idiom as in my answer to put the progress bar in the tab, then when the task is complete you can do tab.setContent(task.getValue()). In this case you must be **very careful** that you don't modify anything that is part of the scene graph in the Task's call method.